# Как "вычленить" из строки все числа и сложить их?

Tags: c++, c

Имеется строка "Как 22дела-11?". Как "вычленить" цифры, а после сложить их ??

Comment: Что было непонятно с первого раза, вот тут? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1039649/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85

Comment: @Harry может он на бумаге программирует, а "отсканить" не смог ? не каждый из нас имеет компьютер , я вот к примеру компьютера не имею и программирую только в библиотеке .

Comment: Я говорю о том, что учебные задания... - и дальше по тексту. Там были расписаны алгоритмы, не было только кода. И если у него нет компьютера - то как он задавал вопрос?...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот алгоритм:**

> 1. подключаем заголовочные файлы для работы с встроенной библиотекой
> 2. считываем строку
> 3. выбираем от туда цифры
> 4. складываем цифры

А вот код:

```
// 1 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char s[256];    // сюда вводим
    char buffer[256];  // сюда фильтруем числа
    int rezultal=0;   // сюда "положим" результат 

    //2
    printf("Введите строку :");
    gets(s);

    //3
    int t_d = 0; // технический датчик
    for (int i =0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        //        if(s[i]<='\x30' || s[i]>='\x39'){
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'){
            buffer[t_d] = s[i]; t_d++;
        }
    }

    //4
    char buffer_t[1]; int asd_t=0;
    for (int i =0;i<strlen(buffer);i++){
        buffer_t[0] = buffer[i];
        // printf("%d:%d\n",i,asd_t);
        asd_t = atoi(buffer_t); // превращаю по одному числу из массива
        rezultal = rezultal+asd_t; // складываю
    }

    printf("результат : %d\n", rezultal);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Евгений вот ответ который ты искал. **Не забывай что алгоритм первостепеннее кода** ,  _реализаций на коде может быть множество а алгоритм по сути это и есть "истинное" решение._

Comment: Хм... А почему было не поместить это в вопрос Евгения в виде ответа??

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов я хотел,  но увы вопрос заблокировали ;_;